# How to set up intent for viewing image that is saved in internal storage with default Android viewer?

Tags: android, android-image

What I am trying to do is to download image from web (its in GIF format, if that changes anything) and show it on screen with zoom/pan capability. I've successfully downloaded image into Bitmap instance *myBitmap*, but ImageView doesnt have zooming feature. So instead I'm willing to present it with default viewer which has zoom/pan features. In order to set up intent I need to provide URI to saved file.
So first I save file into internal storage (also giving access to other apps withe MODE_WORLD_READABLE):

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("scrible",
                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(myTag, e.toString());
    }
```

Then I successfully check its really readable:

```
    File myFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "scrible");
    if (myFile.canRead()) {
        Log.d(myTag, "Its readable");
    }
```

Then I try to set up intent (which gives me error: stopped unexpectedly):

```
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(myFile);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri));
```

I've tried to set up intent separately and it doesnt give error antil call to *startActivity(intent);*

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works well for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(outputFileName)),"image/jpeg");
startActivity(intent);
```

The difference that I see is that you do not call the `setDataAndType`.